# What is $E[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty X_n]$ when $E[X_n] = 0$, $E[X_n^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty X_n < \infty$ a.s?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $(X_n)$ is a sequence of independent real valued random variables, such that $E[X_n] = 0$, $E[X_n^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty X_n < \infty$ a.s. I need to compute $E[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty X_n]$, but I do not know how to start. Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: $E[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty X_n^2] = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ so $E[ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty X_n]$ is finite and so will be  $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty E[  X_n]=0$

Comment: @Henry a quick question, may I ask why we must show first that $E[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n^2] = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ ? What allows us to say this immediately yet we cannot say that $E[\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n] = 0$ immediately?

Comment: @Henry Why is $E\sum X_n$ finite and how does that justify interchange of sum and expectation? I have an example where $\sum E|X_n| =\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\sum X_n$ converges in $L^{2}(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ because it is Cauchy: $ E(\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} X_k)^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} \frac 1 {k^{2}} \to 0$ as $m>n \to \infty$. This implies convergence in $L^{1}$ also. Hence the mean of $\sum X_k$ is the limit of the means of the partial sums which is $0$.

Comment: Could we also use the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: No. DCT is not applicable here. When $X_n$ takes the  value $\pm \frac 1 n$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each the sereis $\sum |X_n|$ diverges with probability $1$ (even though $\sum X_n$ converges with probability $1$!). I see no scope for application of DCT here. @SiemvanBenthem

Comment: How can we conclude the last line. That the mean of the series equals the limit of the mean of the partial sums?

Comment: @SiemvanBenthem If $E|Y_n-Y|^{2} \to 0$ then $E|Y_n-Y| \to 0$ and $EY_n \to EY$. Take $Y_n$ to be the $n-$th partial sum of the series.

Comment: How does the convergence of $EY_n \rightarrow EY$ follow from the $L^1$ convergence? That is not clear to me.

Comment: @SiemvanBenthem $|EY_n-EY|=|E(Y_n-Y)| \leq E|Y_n-Y| \to 0$.

Comment: Yeah sure! Great work :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Would it not have been easier to show that the series is Cauchy in L1?

Comment: @SiemvanBenthem Somehow the fact that $EX_i X_j=EX_iEX_j=0$ has to be used in the proof and we cannot use this  in $E|Y_n-Y|$. It is natural to square $(Y_N-Y)$ and use this fact in the proof.

Comment: True, I understand